# What is the Constant Value of the Underline font in Java?

Tags: java, class, fonts, bold, underline

What is the Constant Value of the Underline font in Java ?

Font.BOLD  **bold** font

Font.ITALIC  *italic* font

What is the UNDERLINE font Constant ?
I try all the available constants but it didn't work .

Comment: stackoverflow ftw.  i was just looking for this today too.  i've been using html to get this for a while, but that brings up a whole host of other problems.

Answer (score 20):

Suppose you wanted a underlined and bolded Serif style font, size=12.

```
Map<TextAttribute, Integer> fontAttributes = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Integer>();
fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
Font boldUnderline = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 12).deriveFont(fontAttributes);
```

If you don't want it bolded, use Font.PLAIN instead of Font.BOLD.  Don't use the getAttributes() method of the Font class.  It will give you a crazy wildcard parameterized type `Map<TextAttribute,?>`, and you won't be able to invoke the put() method.  Sometimes Java can be yucky like that.  If you're interested in why, you can check out this site: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html

Comment: The funny thing is that if you are trying to turn underline off you won't find an `UNDERLINE_OFF` constant. But you can do so by using value `-1`. EG: `fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);`

Comment: +1 for the indication on `put` not working. I just came across it :)
I ended up using `AttributeMap att = (AttributeMap)font.getAttributes();`, as `Font.getAttribute()` uses it.

Comment: @Blake I implemented your code, for underline but I could not see underline. I am using AWT Label where I want to put the underlined string as you explained.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the [Java API Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), it appears that the [`Font` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) does not have a constant for underlining.

However, using the [`Font(Map<? extends AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute,?> attributes)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.util.Map)) constructor, one can give it a `Map` containing the [`TextAttribute`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) and the value to use, in order to specify the font attributes. (Note that the `TextAttribute` class is a subclass of `AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute`)

[`TextAttribute.UNDERLINE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#UNDERLINE) seems like the `TextAttribute` of interest.

**Edit:** There's an example of using `TextAttribute` in the [Using Text Attributes to Style Text](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/text/textattributes.html) section from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Underlining is not a property of the font but of the text segment.  When rendered the text is rendered in the font specified then a line is drawn under it. Depending on what framework you are using, this may be done for you using properties or you may have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For SWT you can use:

```
StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
// make 0123456789 appear underlined
StyleRange style1 = new StyleRange();
style1.start = 0;
style1.length = 10;
style1.underline = true;
text.setStyleRange(style1);
```