# Changing the color of a font and making it underlined

Tags: java, colors, jbutton

I need to make a font underline and blue for a hyperlink in one of my JButtons, but it seems the font class has no obvious way to do this.  I can't use attributedtext because I'm not going to be displaying this with Graphics class.  Is there anyway I can accomplish this?  I just need the title of my JButton to be blue and underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem of not being able to underline text by surrounding my string with  .....  tags.

Answer (score 3):

I am too late to reply. But anyways, I am going to post it here. Maybe it would be helpful to someone.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Label");
HashMap<TextAttribute, Object> textAttrMap = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
textAttrMap.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
textAttrMap.put(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE);

button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(textAttrMap));
```

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/examples/AttributedText.java

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton("OK");
button.setBackground(Color.blue);

Font buttonFont=new Font(button.getFont().getName(),Font.UNDERLINED+Font.BOLD,button.getFont().getSize());  
button.setFont(buttonFont);
```

Comment: I think the font underline constant may actually be "Font.UNDERLINE". Try both.

Comment: Ah, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325840/what-is-the-constant-value-of-the-underline-font-in-java